# Understanding the flow of Finite State Transducer

Tags: nlp, state-machine

[image]

I know what a Finite State Machine is, and I know the concept of FST, but I really don't understand how to input of the table becomes the output. I don't know how to follow the steps of the FST. When we input 11, are both 1's supposed to take turns inside the machine? I really don't get it. Please help me understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input 11 you start (as always) in state 0. The transition labeled 1/0 takes you to state 1, reads the first 1 from the input and outputs 0.

Now there is one 1 of your input left, so you take 1/1 to state 0.

The first step outputs 0, the second one 1, so the total output is 01.

x/y means that the transition reads x and outputs y.